# Setting pan control option to street view when using getPanoramaByLocation

Tags: google-maps-api-3

For known coordinates, I can set the various controls to false by specifying it in the mapOptions object

```js
var mapOptions = {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.869260, -122.254811),
          zoom: 1,
          pov: {
                heading: 165,
                pitch: 0
               },
          addressControl: false,
          panControl: false,
          linksControl: false,
          zoomControl: false,
        };
map = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(mapDiv, mapOptions);
```

However, when using `getPanoramaByLocation`

```
latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34,34);
radius = 500000
var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
var map = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(mapDiv)
        sv.getPanoramaByLocation(latLng, radius, function(data, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                var nearStreetViewLocation = data.location.latLng;              
                map1.setPosition(nearStreetViewLocation);
                map1.setZoom(1);
                map1.setPov({
                                heading: 270,
                                pitch: 0
                                });
                map1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

I cannot find any methods like setPanControl or setZoomControl. How can I modify these controls when I am not declaring options in a single object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For options where no specific setter-method is available use the `set`-method of **`MVCObject`**:

```
map1.set('panControl',true);
```

you may also set multiple options without the constructor by using  `setValues`:

```
map1.setValues({    zoom:1,
                    pov:{
                         heading: 270,
                         pitch: 0
                        },
                    position:nearStreetViewLocation,
                    visible:true,
                    panControl:true,
                    zoomControl:true
               });
```